# How to hook an anonymous function to an Infragistics WebDataGrid event?

Tags: event-handling, infragistics, webdatagrid

From examples I see you can add an event handler to a WebDataGrid on the server side by adding the string name of the function to the behaviors' appropriate property, like in this example:

```
this.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.EditingCore.EditingClientEvents.RowUpdated = "WebDataGrid1_RowUpdated";
```

The problem I see with that is that it forces me to create a javascript global function to service the event.
But how to do if I want to hook an anonymous function on the client side code?
I'd like to write in javascript something like:

```
$find("WebDataGrid1").Behaviors.EditingCore.EditingClientEvents.RowUpdated = function (sender, e) { ... };
```

Is it possible?